# Populate ComboBox from QList<QObject*>

Tags: qt, qml

I was following an example on web to populate combobox, but it did not wok for me and I do not know why!. I have two classes `stock` and `DbCon`, `stock` has three private fields along with public accessor and mutators. `DbCon` has a `Q_Property` and two public function, one returns a database connection and the other creates and returns `stock` list as a `QList<QObject*>`. In `main.cpp` I have created a contextual property named "data" to access `DbCon` from `QML`.

in `main.qml` I have

```
....
ComboBox{
        model: data.stockModel
        textRole: "code"
 }
....
```

in main.cpp

```
DbCon db;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("data", &db);
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
```

in dbcon.h

```
class DbCon:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject*> stockModel READ stockModel)

public:
    explicit DbCon(QObject *parent = 0);
    QSqlDatabase db();
    QList<QObject*> stockModel();
};
```

in implementation of `QList<QObject*> stockModel()` of `dbcon.h`

```
QList<QObject*> data;
....
while (query.next()) {
    stock *s = new stock();
    ....
    data.append(s);
}
return data;
```

and in stock.h

```
class stock : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QString m_name;
    QString m_code;
    int m_id;

public:
    explicit stock(QObject *parent = 0);
    QString name();
    void setname(QString &name);
    QString code();
    void setcode(QString &code);
    int id();
    void setid(int &id);
};
```

When I run the application I get the following message in application output

> QQmlExpression: Expression qrc:/main.qml:16:20 depends on non-NOTIFYable properties:
>       QQuickComboBox::data

and I do not get anything in combobox!

If I create another contextual property in `main.cpp` in this way

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(data));
```

and set `myModel` as model for combobox, it works fine. But I want to do it in this way because `onCurrentIndexChanged` I will call another function that returns another `QList<QObject*>` for a `TableView` of another `qml` file.

---

EDIT: Entrie qml

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width:600
    height:600
    property string contentSource

    Column{
        spacing:10
        ComboBox{
            model: data.stockModel
            textRole: "code"
        }
        Loader {
            id: content
            width: parent.width
            height:400
        }
        Row{
            spacing:10
            Button{
                text: "Page1"
                onClicked: content.source = "Page1.qml"
            }
            Button{
                text: "Page2"
                onClicked: content.source = "Page2.qml"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

By changing `data` to `dataStore` in `main.cpp` and `data.stockModel` to `dataStore.stockModel` in `main.qml` I get following error

> file:///C:/Qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/mingw53_32/qml/QtQuick/Controls.2/ComboBox.qml:62:15: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString

Comment: What is 'data' in QML? How it is defined?

Comment: @AlexanderVX is it not a pointer to `DbCon`? It is defined in `main.cpp` as shown in "in main.cpp" section.

Comment: Better show entire QML part.

Comment: Got it. data is what? In QML for that ComboBox type data is inherited from Item: data : list<Object> This is not really a model?

Comment: @AlexanderVX I've added entire qml at bottom. It works in this way for QString, void function, etc. I do not have to do anything more in qml other than specifying name of function() or name of Q_PROPERY of type QString after `data.`

Comment: So, writing `engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(data)); ` is the only way to create model for combobox ? @AlexanderVX

Comment: I would remove model set in `ComboBox` and try provide it with `id: myBox` and use  `property alias externalModel : myBox.model` to set the model from outside via `externalModel`. There a couple of other things in your code I am not sure of and need to try when I have time. For instance Window and not Rectangle on top: that thing once prevented me from accessing nested QML properties.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130643/discussion-between-emon-haque-and-alexandervx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. Your `stockModel` property should be NOTIFYable, which means that you should define the property with e.g. `Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject*> stockModel READ stockModel NOTIFY stockModelChanged)` and provide a `void stockModelChanged(const QList<QObject *> &)` signal in the `DbCon` class.
2. `stock::name()` must be a property too, so you need to declare that with `Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name NOTIFY nameChanged)` and provide a `void nameChanged(const QString &)` signal in the `stock` class as well.

Comment: It also works if I do not parameterize `stockModelChanged` and `nameChanged`. In this case I can use `nameChanged()` instead of  `nameChanged(const QString &)`. Is there any case where I have no way to avoid parameter in function that signals?

Comment: Depends on what functions the signal will be connected to. A signal `nameChanged(const QString &)` can be connected both to a function that takes a `const QString &` parameter, and to a function that doesn't take any parameters at all. Looks like QML is not interested in the value in the signal itself, but uses the getter to retrieve it.

Comment: Probably qml requires a signal to be emitted somewhere to call the getter @E4z9. In setter of  `name` I have provided that by writing `emit nameChanged()`